# Express this integral in terms of $\zeta(s)$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

How to express the following integral: $$s\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st} \psi(e^t) dt$$ where $\psi(x)$ represents the second [Chebyshev function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function), in terms of $\zeta(s)$?

Comment: Please feel free to edit if this isn't what you had in mind (you need to put `{}` around things you want LaTeX to treat as a single group).

Comment: $\psi(x)$ is the Chebyshev function here, no?

Comment: Yes, $\psi$ is the Chebyshev function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First change the variables via $x=e^t$, $\log(x)=t$, $dx/x=dt$ and the Laplace Transform becomes the Mellin Transform.  (The integral is then from $1$ to $\infty$, but since $\Psi(x)=0$ for $0\le x<1$, you can extend the integral to be from $0$ to $\infty$.)

Then substitute 
$$
\Psi(x)=\sum_{n<x}\Lambda(n).
$$

Now interchange the sum and integral to get

$$
s\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Lambda(n)\int_n^\infty x^{-s-1}dx.
$$

Finally, compute the integral and see that you have the series expansion of
$$
-\frac{\zeta^\prime(s)}{\zeta(s)}.
$$

(For details, see my book *A Primer of Analytic Number Theory*.)

Comment: And a very nice book it is!